# Zend framework - send a message from the current action to another action in Controller

Tags: zend-framework

In Zend framework: how can I send a message from the current action to another action in Controller?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? In a typical request, the router identifies a single request to be dispatched. So, how does this second action fit into your execution flow? Are you redirecting to another action? Forwarding to another action? Or are you calling other actions directly?

Comment: @David Weinraub I am in userController, action changePassword. After user change pw, I want to redirect to loginAction and print out message "Successful!!"
I have tried to use  `$this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage('Successful');`
but it does not work :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very simple example of using FlashMessenger, so you can use it on your code:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $messages = $this->_helper->FlashMessenger->getMessages('actions');
    echo $messages[0];
}


public function redirectAction()
{
    $this->_helper->FlashMessenger->addMessage("Your message", 'actions');
    $this->_redirect('index/index');
}
```

If you point in browser at 'redirect' action, you should get indexAction with the message.