# send parameter from controller to view zend

Tags: zend-framework, request, param

I want to send parameter from action to view which is not it's view, since each action has it's .phtml view . I want to redirect to index.phtml  page when I am in editAction

inside the edit action I make

```
$this->_helper->redirector->gotoRoute(array('module' => 'visits', 'controller' => 'visit', 'action' => 'index'), 'visit');
```

so I can't use like this in the controller action

```
$this->message="Successfully saved";
```

I search in google I found that I can use

```
$this->getRequest()->setParam('message',"Successfully saved");
```

but How can I get the param in .PHTML page

Comment: Can you be more specific on what your "view which is not it's view" is? Where and how do you render this other view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use flash messenger , its capable to do such these tasks

> FlashMessenger is a helper that allows you to store messages between
>   requests. The most common use I have for it is for a "saved" message
>   after doing an edit of an item that then redirects back to a list.

examples :

http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/zend-frameworks-flash-messenger-action-helper/

Comment: When I  make echo $this->_helper->flashMessenger->getMessages(); in the index page, this error occur Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: check this basic example : http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelper.flashmessenger.basicusage

Comment: Don't do this `$this->view->messages = $this->_helper->flashMessenger->getMessages();` in a view, but in an action! From your view, `echo $this->messages`. Of course, you can't get the message if you're still in the same request, you need to redirect first.

Comment: @liyali, The point is I want to redirect to another view, when I make $this->view this mean the action view where as I redirect to another view.

Comment: Another explanation for the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400000/zend-framework-send-a-message-from-the-current-action-to-another-action-in-con

Comment: Yeah of course `$this->view->messages = $this->_helper->flashMessenger->getMessages();` must be written in the action where your request has been redirected.